# Compiler error in java: identifier expected

Tags: java, compiler-errors

At the line

```
for(int x,=0; x<=numberOfLockers; x++);
```

I get an *identifier expected* error. What's wrong there? This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);   
    int studentVisitCount = 0;   

    System.out.print("Enter the number of lockers: ");   
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int numberOfLockers = console.nextInt();   

    for(int x,=0; x<=numberOfLockers; x++);
    {
        if(x%y==0)
        {
            studentVisitCount++;
        }
        for(int y=0; y<=x; y++)
        {
            if(studentVisitCount%2!=0)
            {
                System.out.print(y+" ");
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The number of lockers and students are: "+numberOfLockers);   
    System.out.print("The locker numbers of lockers that are left open at the end of the game are: ");  
}
```

Comment: Remove `,` from `int x,=0` on that line.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the language tag..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I edited the tags of your question and the question text, tried to make it more readable. Remember, the TAGS attract the right audience to your question, so if you use irrelevant tags you get the wrong audience and the audience you want don't see that question.
It is also assumed that everyone here is trying to be helpful. So there is no need to ask for help separately.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community!

You have basically answered your question. You have a trivial syntax error in your for-loop.

```java
for(int x,=0; x<=numberOfLockers; x++);
         ^
      remove ','
```

> Please brush up on your basic Java.

**Cheers!**